# why window.onscroll function acting weird?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to coding and everything but have gained a pretty good understanding of everything from tutorials and all that stuff.

I'm trying to make this logo change when someone scrolls down. It is working, but i'm trying to figure out why it quickly toggles the classes at the very beginning when the page first loads and someone scrolls down. It only does it at the beginning, but after that it works fine.

Any tips or advice?? Thank you!!

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  navScroll()
};

function navScroll() {
  var logoNav = document.getElementById("bgNav");

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    logoNav.className = "play";
  } else {
    logoNav.className = "playBack";
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

@keyframes play60 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -30000px 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes play60Back {
  0% {
    background-position: -30000px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

#bgNav.play {
  animation-name: play60;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#bgNav.playBack {
  animation-name: play60Back;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#bgNav {
  height: 117px;
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-timing-function: steps(60);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://metro1.000webhostapp.com/metro-nav-animated.svg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" id="bgNav"></div>

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Seems ok to me can you explain more about your problem?

Comment: if you click "run code snippet" and scroll down, you'll see the logo quickly switch to the end of the animation and then goes back to doing its normal thing. It only does it the first time you scroll. So just click the "run code snippet" then scroll and each time you do that it will do it again.

Comment: sorry, its sort of hard to explain exactly what i mean!!

Comment: You need to add a check to see if that element already has those classes, otherwise your adding a class to the element every time someone scrolls! Not just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine

```
} else if(logoNav.className === "play") {
    logoNav.className = "playBack";
}
```

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  navScroll()
};

function navScroll() {
  var logoNav = document.getElementById("bgNav");

  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    logoNav.className = "play";
  } else if(logoNav.className === "play") {
    logoNav.className = "playBack";
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.container {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

@keyframes play60 {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -30000px 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes play60Back {
  0% {
    background-position: -30000px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

#bgNav.play {
  animation-name: play60;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#bgNav.playBack {
  animation-name: play60Back;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#bgNav {
  height: 117px;
  width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-timing-function: steps(60);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://metro1.000webhostapp.com/metro-nav-animated.svg");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" id="bgNav"></div>

  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! I have a couple instances where something similar would happen, so now I know where and why an "else if" is needed :)